# Android: Imageview getting resized while the height of the object above is altered

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Here is my layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.homerevise.studyapp.activity.HomeScreenActivity"
    tools:showIn= "@layout/app_bar_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_colour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/path_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_more"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/more"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_page_title"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/page_title" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_happy_student"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/image_page_title"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_page_title"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/happy_student" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_subject_title"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/subject_title" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/image_subject_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecentlyLearned"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerView"
            android:text="Recently Learned"
            android:textColor="#2A3E61"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_Recently_Learned"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtRecentlyLearned"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/recently_learned"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"/>
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

If the layout height of the recycler view changes the imageview txtRecentlyLearned gets reseized. It becomes too small. Like even if the height of the recycler view is changed to 250dp the image size drops considerably. The Imageview should not get resized at all ever.

How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Played around a little with the layout weight and relative views for now it seems to work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.homerevise.studyapp.activity.HomeScreenActivity"
tools:showIn= "@layout/app_bar_main">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rel_colour"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
android:background="@drawable/path_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_more"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/more"/>

   

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_page_title"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/page_title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_happy_student"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/image_page_title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_page_title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/happy_student" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_subject_title"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/subject_title" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_subject_title"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRecentlyLearned"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Recently Learned"
        android:textColor="#2A3E61"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_Recently_Learned"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtRecentlyLearned"
        android:src="@drawable/recently_learned"
        />


</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move textView and imageView outside the RelativeLayout to the parent LinearLayout and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the RelativeLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRecentlyLearned"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_Recently_Learned"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/recently_learned" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you have asked but now the relative layout containing the recycler view is no longer visible. Even the imageview of id image_subject_title is gone.

Comment: I actually tried putting image and text views back in to the relative view. But this time I shifted all other content of the relativeview to the one above it. And gave each relative views a weight of 4 and 1 respectively. It worked for me.